# How to in Magento enable Custom Payment methods for only allowed ip address

Tags: magento

How to in Magento enable Custom Payment methods for only allowed ip address that recorded in System->Configuration->Developer->Developer Client Restrictions

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011348/disable-payment-options-only-cash-on-delivery-for-particular-product-magento) post, and put your condition in `toOptionArray()` method.