# Do not show cash on delivery methods for some specific cities

Tags: magento, payment

Is there any way to display/hide "Cash on delivery" payment method for some specific cities.
Can anyone guide me how/where to start code for this to achieve this custom functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Disable payment options-only cash on delivery for particular product-magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011348/disable-payment-options-only-cash-on-delivery-for-particular-product-magento)

Using `payment_method_is_active` observer you could load the current checkout session quote and check what city the order is be ship to.

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$shipping = $checkout->getShippingAddress();

$cashOnDeliveryCities = array('city name 1','city name 2',..)

if(in_array($shipping->getCity(), $cashOnDeliveryCities)){
    $result->isAvailable = true;
}else{
    $result->isAvailable = false;
}
```

Comment: After bit modification in the code i have been able to achieve this functionality. Thank you for your help.