# Change payment method each time the customer check out in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, payment

I am using magento 1.7 i am having 3 payment methods so i want to display one payment method randomly among the 3 payment methods on during customers checkout.waiting for a valuable suggestion.Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi , you need to set in such a way that only one payment method will be visible randomly right?

Comment: yes but all the 3 payment method should come in the random order ie,each time customer checkouts he need to see different payment methods.Thanks for Ur reply

Comment: just in random order not any show/hide or anything right ?

Comment: yes help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Disable payment options-only cash on delivery for particular product-magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011348/disable-payment-options-only-cash-on-delivery-for-particular-product-magento) or [Cash On Delivery activated Admin Only ( Not Frontend enabled ) - Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022921/cash-on-delivery-activated-admin-only-not-frontend-enabled-magento/14023210#14023210)

```
class MagePal_PaymentFilterByProduct_ActivePaymentMethod
{
    //get all active (enable) payment method
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
       $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();

       //Get current customer id

       //remove method below after check if customer place order before or first order

       foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
           if($paymentModel->canUseCheckout() == 1){
                $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
                $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                    'label'   => $paymentTitle,
                    'value' => $paymentCode,
                );
           }
        }

        return $methods;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is it mean by ( Not Frontend enabled ) - Magento?

Comment: Frontend  = website that customer purchase from (backend = admin placing order for customer)